# ruby on rails scope for date and time query

Tags: database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I want to make a scope by name **recent_flag** which return products of last 40 days. i have a code like this, and thinking not perfect, is there any efficient way to make scope for my requirement.

```
scope :recent_flag, -> { where(product.created_at <= Time.now - 40.day)}
```

my database is **postgresql**.

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Comment: @pavan, sorry for late reply, yes it was right but i use another way and thanks your code made me though different :)

check my answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You can modify your scope to

```
scope :recent_flag, -> { where(product.created_at > 40.days.ago)}
```

**Note:** Didn't tested.Try and let me know.

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes it was right but i use another way and thanks your code made me though different :)

check my answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
scope :recent_flag, -> { where("created_at > ?",(Time.now - 40.days).beginning_of_day)}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: scope :recent_flag, -> { Product.where(["created_at >=? AND created_at <=?", Date.today - 14.days,Date.today]) }

Comment: see my answer. how is that ?

Answer (score 1):

its the best way i thought.

```
scope :recent, -> { where(["created_at >= ?", Date.today - 14.days]) }
```